# MDX filter data

Tags: mdx

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterCaption] AS  [Estate].[Week].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION
MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterValue] AS  [Estate].[Week].CURRENTMEMBER.UNIQUENAME 
MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterLevel] AS  [Estate].[Week].CURRENTMEMBER.LEVEL.ORDINAL 

SELECT 
{[Measures].[ParameterCaption], [Measures].[ParameterValue], [Measures].[ParameterLevel]} ON COLUMNS 
, 
NON EMPTY ( 
ORDER (
    EXCEPT( [Estate].[Week].[ALL].CHILDREN
    , { [Estate].[Week]}) 
, ( [Estate].[Week].MEMBERVALUE)
, ASC
) 
) ON ROWS 
From  [EstateRpt]
WHERE Filter([V Estate Weekly Rpt].[Week].CHILDREN, [V Estate Weekly Rpt].[Week].MEMBERVALUE = 'NONE')
```

Hi, i am new to the MDX. I want to filter the week which is not equal to "NONE"? by default, week is set the "NONE", so it will appear the NONE data in cube. I want to filter this NONE.

I do try the WHERE clause but it show the error to me which i do not figure out what is the problem

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: Opps, sorry that i forgot to reply. Ya ur answer is help me to solve my problem. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter out `'NONE'` then you need to use this in your filter:

```
 <> 'NONE'
```

Also you need to use CurrentMember within your filter like this example:

```
SELECT 
    {
      [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2006]&[7]
     ,[Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20050220]
    }
  * 
    {[Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]} ON COLUMNS
 ,
    {[Product].[Category].Children}
  * 
    {[Geography].[Geography].[Country].MEMBERS} ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE 
  Filter
  (
    [Geography].[State-Province].MEMBERS
   ,
    [Geography].[State-Province].CurrentMember.Member_Caption <> 'California'
  );
```